# How to get the current position of a robot (C++)?

Tags: c++, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I try to get the situation of my robot using the following code:

```
tf::TransformListener listener;
tf::StampedTransform transform;
listener.lookupTransform("/move_base/local_costmap/global_frame", "/move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame", ros::Time::now(), transform);
```

and use it using the following methods:

```
transform.getOrigin().x()
transform.getOrigin().y()
//...
```

My problem is when I run this code, I get the the following error:

```
[ERROR] [..., ...]: "move_base/local_costmap/global_frame" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

But when I check the *"move_base/local_costmap/global_frame"* parameter existence (the same with the *"move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame"* parameter), I find that it exists well and is settled to *'odom'* value (respectively *'base_link'*).

I also tried to write directly *"odom"* and *"base_link"* instead of *"move_base/local_costmap/global_frame"* and *"move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame"* but I have the same error:

```
[ERROR] [..., ...]: "odom" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

However, when I do:

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

I have the following tree:
[image: image description]
The first and the third frames are those which interest me.

Moreover, when I use the command:

```
rosrun tf tf_monitor odom base_link
```

I have this:

```
RESULTS: for odom to base_link
Chain is: odom -> base_footprint -> base_link
Net delay     avg = 0.00599856: max = 0.016

Frames:
Frame: base_footprint published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.000963 Max Delay: 0.005
Frame: base_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.500052 Max Delay: 0

All Broadcasters:
Node: unknown_publisher 146.156 Hz, Average Delay: -0.102412 Max Delay: 0.005
```

If someone can help me, I will be very grateful,
lfr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235280/how-to-get-the-current-position-of-a-robot-(c++)-?/) by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2016-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-05-27**:
Check my update with waitforTransform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to pass the frame name directly to lookupTransform and not the name of a parameter that contains the frame name. You can't expect such a function to decide if you passed the name of a frame or of a parameter.

Next, you should add a listener.waitForTransform before you try to look up. You just created the listener so it had no time to collect any transformations on the /tf-topic.

BTW: You should have a look at TF2. It reduces the used bandwidth and gets rid of the republishing of static transformations.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-05-27**:
Thank you for answering me.
I already tried to use *'odom'* instead of *"move_base/local_costmap/global_frame"* and *'base_link'* instead of *"move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame"* but it generates the same error with *'odom'*.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-05-27**:
What is published on /tf and /tf_static?

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-05-27**:
On /tf, a lot of things are published non-stop but nothing is published on /tf_static.
This is a sample of data published on /tf:

```
transforms:
```

- header:
  seq: 0
  stamp:
  secs: 77
  nsecs: 129000000
  frame_id: odom
  child_frame_id: base_footprint

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-05-27**:
...

```
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: 0.000368870873302
    y: 0.000194895575539
    z: 0.0839691068639
  rotation: 
    x: -3.22346543618e-07
    y: 4.25625394189e-07
    z: 0.000436463216874
    w: 0.99999990475
```

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-05-27**:
Thank you, it works successfully !!
Really thank you.